# Lining up images using absolute css to text that is wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I have a long page with text that is resizing in width (and height) depending on the width of the browser size. So for example I have:

```
 <h1 id="loc1">Title</h1>

 <p>bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy 
 bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy 
 bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy</p>

 <h2 id="loc2">Subtitle</h2>

 <p>bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy 
 bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy
 bodycopy bodycopy</p>
```

and I want to line the top right corner of image1 (using absolute CSS) to the top left corner of "Title" and the top right corner of image2 to the top left corner of "Subtitle". But since the text wraps, the absolute location of the titles changes.

For example is it possible to put an ID to "Subtitle" (something like Subtitle and then us JQuery or Javascript to assign the CSS absolute location of image2 to be based on the X and Y location of 'loc2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an image tag in there but you can just float the image to the left to create the sort of effect you're talking about. (With out the need for absolute positioning) Note that i also wrapped each title/img/paragraph set in a div

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPja2/

```
<div id="one">
    <img id="newImage" src="#">

    <h1 id="loc1">Title</h1>

    <p>bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy           bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy bodycopy</p>
</div>
```

and use some CSS similar to:

```
#newImage {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT:** As per the discussion in the comments
new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPja2/1/

changed the css

```
#newImage {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
#loc1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

and added some JS

```
var position = $("#loc1").position();
$("#newImage").css("top", position.top);
$("#newImage").css("left", position.left - 70);
```

Comment: No sorry, that wont work. I need to assign the location of the image manually using js or jq, after the page has rendered. I can't have it as a normal line item as you have above. #newImage for example would have to have {position: absolute; } something like that (which I assume I would have to do like document.getElementByID["newImage"].style.top = [calculation of H1 top] etc. I realize this isn't the normal way of doing it, doesn't work for my layout.

Comment: I see, what about jquery.position? it returns a set of positions relative to the objects parent http://api.jquery.com/position/ that can get the numbers for the top/left of your title and then you can set the image to say -70px of those positions

Comment: Ya, that is what I was looking for. Haven't tested it yet, but looks great. Thx.